# Deploy Grafana on Azure Server

Tags: azure, server, grafana

Any one please suggest how to build grafana Project to deploy on azure server. I am not able to make a build (dist folder) of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but a Grafana user recently documented all the steps:

https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-azure-webapp/1524?u=daniellee

It is almost the same as the [build from source](http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/) instructions with some Azure specific steps.